# Linq - SQL query conversion

Tags: sql, linq

Can some one help me to convert this query to linq? I dont know how to use union and then sum in linq.

```
SELECT Patientname, SUM(A)AS Trec
  FROM (SELECT Pm.Patientname, COUNT(*)AS A
          FROM Facilitycheckinholdorder Fcho
              INNER JOIN Medordertype Mot ON Fcho.Orderseq = Mot.Orderseq
              JOIN Patientmaster Pm ON Mot.Patientseq = Pm.Patientseq
                   AND Fcho.Filleddate BETWEEN '2011-09-01 00:00:00:000' AND '2012-10-16 00:00:00:000'
                   AND Mot.Facilityid = 139
         GROUP BY Pm.Patientname
       UNION ALL
       SELECT Pm.Patientname, COUNT(*)AS A
         FROM Rxqdeliveryholdorder Rdho
              INNER JOIN Medordertype Mot ON Rdho.Orderseq = Mot.Orderseq
              JOIN Patientmaster Pm ON Mot.Patientseq = Pm.Patientseq
                   AND Rdho.Filleddate BETWEEN '2011-09-01 00:00:00:000' AND '2012-10-16 00:00:00:000'
                   AND Mot.Facilityid = 139
         GROUP BY Pm.Patientname
      ) AS Trec
  GROUP BY Patientname;
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is not a real question, but I've tried my best...

```
var lst1 =
    from fhco in facilitycheckinholdorder
    join mot in meordertype on mot.orderseq equals fhco.orderseq
    join pm in patientmaster on mot.patientseq equals pm.patientseq
    where 
        fcho.FilledDate >= new DateTime(2011, 9, 1)
        fcho.FilledDate <= new DateTime(2012, 10, 16)
    select pm;
var lst2 =
    from rdho in rxqdeliveryholdorder
    join mot in meordertype on rdho.orderseq equals mot.orderseq
    join pm in patientmaster on moit.patientseq equals pm.patientseq
    where 
        fcho.FilledDate >= new DateTime(2011, 9, 1)
        fcho.FilledDate <= new DateTime(2012, 10, 16)
    select pm;
var res = 
    from item in lst1.Union(lst2)
    select new { Name = item.patientname, Count = lst1.Count() + lst2.Count() };
```

Answer (score 0):

Key points:

- Your outermost query seems redundant.
- Your names are not common C# style, and it makes them difficult to read.
- `UNION ALL` corresponds to `Concat`, not `Union`.
- Getting the `Concat` out of the way early lets you streamline the query. You could do this in the SQL.

.

```
var result =
    from order in Queryable.Concat(
        FacilityCheckInHoldOrder.Select(o => new { o.OrderSeq, o.FilledDate }),
        RxqDeliveryHoldOrder    .Select(o => new { o.OrderSeq, o.FilledDate }))
    where order.FilledDate >= new DateTime(2011,  9,  1) &&
          order.FilledDate <  new DateTime(2012, 10, 16)
    join type in MedOrderType.Where(t => t.FacilityID == 139)
        on order.OrderSeq equals type.OrderSeq
    join patient in PatientMaster
        on type.PatientSeq equals patient.PatientSeq
    group by patient.PatientName into grp
    select new
    {
        PatientName = grp.Key,
        Trec = grp.Count()
    };
```